# The quadratic function problem

Tags: quadratics

$H(p,q)$ and $I(r,s)$ are two points on $f(x)=x^2-6x+11$. If $p+q=6$, what is the relationship between $q$ and $s$?

Comment: What did you try to do?

Comment: Well, if $p+r=6$ there is an obvious (to me, anyway) relationship between $q$ and $s$.  Is there a typo in the question?

Comment: There are no mistakes in the question, I have solved this question but I want to see other methods out there, I'm so sorry about the bad way of writing the question tho

Comment: @AsriHasvan you have solved it. Can you edit your solution in the question?